# Ruby Execution of Process-Related Shell Commands Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails server, whilst in Development mode, I have a need to manage running processes, such as by the `pgrep` command. When I attempt to execute `system("pgrep MyProcess")` the Rails server hangs indefinitely. I also tried the backtick version. When I use `Ctrl-C`, I don't get much useful information about where the process was stuck:

```
[1] pry(main)> `pgrep #{process}`
^CInterrupt:
from /Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'
[2] pry(main)> system("pgrep #{process}")
^CInterrupt:
from (pry):2:in `system'
```

I have verified that other system commands work, such as `system("rm -rf #{filename}")`.

Comment: Does the `pgrep` work in the regular terminal?

Comment: when you issue ``pgrep #{process}`` do you see it running (ps, top, etc) ?

Comment: @Ruslan yes the exact same command works in the terminal if I exit the Ruby shell. @

Comment: @xlembouras I have tried both (running and non running) processes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you know the backtick and system calls are synchronous?

Comment: Yes; this suggests that the execution itself is hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, a simple reboot of the impacted machine fixed this one. Go figure.